# ¿Como obtener el nombre de los campos de una tabla especifica en una base de datos mysql?

Tags: mysql

Lo que necesito es poder obtener el nombre de todos los campos de una tabla especifica. Probe con este codigo y funciona pero solo desde el gestor de la base de datos, en mi caso mysql-front

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database()
AND TABLE_NAME = 'nombre de la tabla';
```

El problema es que este codigo no especifica el nombre de la base de datos, y cuando quiero acceder desde c# no sabe en que base buscar por lo que no me devuelve nada.
Me gustaria saber si hay alguna manera de especificar de que base es la tabla.

Comment: ¿Qué uso les vas a dar a esos campos? ¿Es para trabajar con ellos? Si no, te recomiendo SHOW CREATE TABLE TUTABLA

Comment: Para seleccionar una DB, debes poner antes de tu consulta: `USE Tu_Base_De_Datos;`

Answer (score 2):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
select ordinal_position, column_name, data_type
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_schema = 'nombre_de_la_B.D.' 
          and table_name = 'nombre_de_la_tabla'
    order by 1;
```

Saludos.